# How to dispose of GCM's InternalServerError?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, internal-server-error

I purpose to offer push notification service using GCM.
e.g. Client reserve time for push, then the server push notification at that time.
if some clients reserve same time, server push notifications continuously.
Sometimes gcm response is InternalserverError but some client receive notification and others don't receive notification.
what's the problem??

Comment: For the `Client reserve time for push` do you mean reserve time for your backend node.js? For `others don't receive notification` is it a delay?